# Count/Frequency Distribution of Character Occurrences in File, Including Non-Visible

Tags: java, hashmap

My goal is to create a frequency distribution of every character in large flat files (1GB+) for later database import.  Ideally the output would be a list of ASCII characters each one followed by a count.

I'm currently using a hashmap to create a distribution of every value in a string, and it kind of works, I'm just not sure how to implement this on a large file.   Additionally, in my output the CR and LF (or /r /n) characters result in a new line with the count on the next.

Here is the current code:

```
public class CharCount{
public static void main(String[] args) {

String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890,.)(/\\<>?!@#$%^&*_-+=\r\n";

char[] arr = s.toCharArray();

HashMap <Character,Integer> count = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

for (char c : arr) {

try {
count.put(c, count.get(c)+1);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {

count.put(c, 1);
}
}

for (Character c: count.keySet()) {
System.out.println(c + " = " + (int)c + " = " + count.get(c));
}
}
}
```

The ideal output would look something like:

> 000   NUL 4124435 
>   001   SOH 0
>   002   STX 0
>   003   ETX 0
>   .....
>   253   ý   0
>   254   þ   0
>   255   ÿ   0

Definitely appreciate any help!

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you have encountered?  (e.g. how is your actual output difference from your ideal?)

Comment: Don't use a catch(NullPointerException) to handle the case where the char is not in the map. Test if count.get(c) returns null instead. It's much easier to read, and also faster. Exceptions are for exceptional cases.

Comment: The main problem is applying this logic to a large file, rather than a short string. Regarding the output, mine appears to be jumbled, the ideal would be having it ordered.  Thanks for the (NullPointerException) tip JB!

Comment: The logic would be exactly the same. Just use a BufferedReader wrapping a FileReader and read the file char by char, modifying the map at each char. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html. To have your map sorted, use a SortedMap rather than a HashMap.

Comment: Great info JB, not sure how to flag that as my solution, but should be all I needed, thanks!

Comment: As an alternative to checking for null (the char not in the Map) you could "preposition" every character with a count of 0 in the map.  e.g. `for (char c=0; c<256; c++) map.put(c, Integer.valueOf(0));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only handling ASCII characters, i.e., in the range 0-255, it would be a simpler to just have an integer (or maybe a long) array[256], then read the file, in effect, a char at a time (of course, you'd use buffering or NIO for speed) and increment the appropriate bin.

That said, your HashMap code looks reasonable and I'm not sure what is your question or problem???

Comment: I'm not sure how to read a file one character at a time, and I wasn't sure if the HashMap method would work for very large files (1GB+).  Pretty new to this, thanks for feedback!

Comment: As @JB Niznet also noted, your results are not ordered because HashMap is not ordered.  (or at least, not in the way you expect).  He also described how to "read one char at a time" while buffering for performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you're only going to be dealing with ASCII data, it would be *much* faster to implement this using an `int[256]` array rather than a hash map.

Regarding `\r` and `\n`, just handle them like you appear to be handling the other characters below space. (You probably should handle space like that as well–by printing its name rather than the character itself.)